# Should I use the RDB for this similarity case

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

My use case is given 6000 stores which each of them has its own products to sell. I want to find the most similar store for one specified store in terms of the products it sell.

I am come from the RDB world. It seems it is not easy to do it in RDB. But for the graph db it also not clear for me how to achieve it since there is no link between the stores. I've checked the closeness:
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#closeness-centrality

Basically, my question is:

- How to model the graph? should I just create unlinked vertex to represent the store or create vertex to represent the product?
- What Recipe i should use to archive this if it is possible? I assume it should be straightforward.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it your intent to store the data for all 6000 stores in a single database on a single host or do you want the data to be stored in a distributed database across some number of hosts, i.e. each store hosts its data locally or data is stored in regional data centers?

Comment: Will be in a single database for analysis purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can find a number of example recommendation systems that have been developed by the Neo4j community [here](https://neo4j.com/graphgists/?category=real-time-recommendations). This will give you some ideas on model approaches as well as accompanying queries.

You may also interesting the [Neo4j Graph Algorithms](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/), which have closeness centrality, similarity functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is very easy and efficient to handle with a graph DB because of the power of relationships.

Let's say you use neo4j, and have `Store` and `Product` nodes connected by `OFFERS` relationships. There is a single `Product` node for each distinct product, and multiple `Store`s can be connected to the same `Product` node. Here is an example of a single relationship:

```
(:Store {id: 1234, name: 'My Store'})-[:OFFERS]->(:Product {id: 9999, name: "Fido Treats"})
```

To find the store that offers the most products in common with 'My Store', you can use the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COUNT` to count the number of shared products, `ORDER BY` to sort in descending order, and `LIMIT 1` to pick the result with the highest count:

```
MATCH (s:Store)-[:OFFERS]->(p:Product)<-[:OFFERS]-(other:Store)
WHERE s.id = 1234
RETURN s, other, COUNT(p) AS commonCount
ORDER BY commonCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```